# After login I get blank admin pages

Tags: 7

I have a D7 site up and running and working fine. Today I logged in to update some content, but I saw that the admin pages just show the system messages about necessary module updates and that's it. I tried several pages and they all show the same, no content except for the message on top. I can see the site content, but whatever link I click within the admin pages will show the right URL but the same content as the attached image.

Just a few months ago I logged in and everything was okay. What could be causing this? Any help is appreciated.

[image: 7]

Comment: Check the admin theme block settings, make sure 'main system content' is output

Comment: I can't see the settings, it throws the same blank page. However I know for sure that setting hasn't changed, I'm the only one who could have done it and I know I haven't.

Comment: Security updates available. A few months ago. Uh, uh. Sounds dangerous.

Comment: Try looking at the block table and see what blocks are enabled. This is cryptic in Drupal 7, but you could try changing status 1 to all system module blocks. However maybe blocks aren't being displayed because of a problem with the site's code (modified/hacked).